# MongoDB: BIllions of documents in a collection

Tags: mongodb

I need to load 6.6 billion bigrams into a collection but I can't find any information on the best way to do this.

Loading that many documents onto a single primary key index would take forever but as far as I'm aware mongo doesn't support the equivalent of partitioning?

Would sharding help? Should I try and split the data set over many collections and build that logic into my application?

Comment: See if this answer of mine helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783212/how-to-load-100-million-records-into-mongodb-with-scala-for-performance-testing/6786925#6786925

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It's hard to say what the optimal bulk insert is -- this partly depends on the size of the objects you're inserting and other immeasurable factors. You could try a few ranges and see what gives you the best performance. As an alternative, some people like using mongoimport, which is pretty fast, but your import data needs to be json or csv. There's obviously mongodrestore, if the data is in BSON format.

Mongo can easily handle billions of documents and can have billions of documents in the one collection but remember that the [maximum document size is 16mb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents). There are many folk with billions of documents in MongoDB and there's lots of discussions about it on the [MongoDB Google User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mongodb-user). Here's a [document](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Using+a+Large+Number+of+Collections) on using a large number of collections that you may like to read, if you change your mind and want to have multiple collections instead. The more collections you have, the more indexes you will have also, which probably isn't what you want.

Here's a [presentation](https://www.10gen.com/presentations/mongosf2011/craigslist) from Craigslist on inserting billions of documents into MongoDB and the guy's [blogpost](http://blog.zawodny.com/2011/03/06/mongodb-pre-splitting-for-faster-data-loading-and-importing/).

It does look like sharding would be a good solution for you but typically sharding is used for scaling across multiple servers and a lot of folk do it because they want to scale their writes or they are unable to keep their working set (data and indexes) in RAM. It is perfectly reasonable to start off with a single server and then move to a shard or replica-set as your data grows or you need extra redundancy and resilience.

However, there are other users use multiple mongods to get around locking limits of a single mongod with lots of writes. It's obvious but still worth saying but a multi-mongod setup is more complex to manage than a single server. If your IO or cpu isn't maxed out here, your working set is smaller than RAM and your data is easy to keep balanced (pretty randomly distributed), you should see improvement (with sharding on a single server). As a FYI, there is potential for memory and IO contention. With 2.2 having improved [concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/2.2+Release+Notes) with [db locking](http://blog.serverdensity.com/2012/05/23/goodbye-global-lock-mongodb-2-0-vs-2-2/), I suspect that there will be much less of a reason for such a deployment.

You need to plan your move to sharding properly, i.e. think carefully about choosing your shard key. If you go this way then it's best to pre-split and turn off the balancer. It will be counter-productive to be moving data around to keep things balanced which means you will need to decide up front how to split it. Additionally, it is sometimes important to design your documents with the idea that some field will be useful for sharding on, or as a primary key.

Here's some good links -

- [Choosing a Shard Key](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Choosing+a+Shard+Key)
- [Blog post on shard keys](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2011/01/04/how-to-choose-a-shard-key-the-card-game/)
- [Overview presentation on sharding](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/sharding-overview)
- [Presentation on Sharding Best Practices](http://www.10gen.com/presentations/MongoNYC-2012/Sharding-Best-Practices-Advanced)

Comment: If you're iterating over larger amounts of data like you're suggesting, it'll be slow in any database, including the other big database solutions.

Comment: No @ChrisHoughton, mysql innodb engine dramatically fast with inserts/selects even > 6.5 billions of records, of course with composite indexing and partitioning. But when I've tryed mongodb over the 1 billion records - it was awefull especially with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 8):

You can absolutely [shard data in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction) (which partitions across N servers on the [shard key](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction#ShardingIntroduction-ShardKeys)).  In fact, that's one of it's core strengths.  There is no need to do that in your application.

For most use cases, I would strongly recommend doing that for 6.6 billion documents.  In my experience, MongoDB performs better with a number of mid-range servers rather than one large one.

Comment: This is only for a single server. Even say creating 4 shards would still be holding billions of records per shard...

Comment: At least when I worked with high-volume MongoDB 6 months ago, locking was *very* suboptimal.  Even if your shards are on the same physical server, you may see better performance running multiple MongoDB instances on the server (then again, I don't think that configuration is officially supported).  Benchmark your use cases.

Comment: Also... Mongo performance falls off a cliff (relatively) if you don't have enough RAM to keep the working set (frequently accessed documents) in memory.  Be aware of that.

Comment: @EricJ. isn't more the case that the index(es) need to fit within memory?

Comment: @D-Klotz: Both, really. At least when I was using MongoDB at the time. Contrast SQL Server, where indices in memory is often the most critical aspect.