# MongoDB performance while migration from MYSQL to MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, transactions

I have a database in MySQL consisting 10 tables.
There is complex mapping between these tables. Now I want to migrate the same database to MongoDB .
I created a sample database for the same in MongoDB .The mappings in the database are making the document complex.

Say there are a 100,00 rows in a table and it is mapped with 3 or 4 tables in MySQL in that case for MongoDB the amount of data for single document will be large.
I have few questions regarding the same -

- As MongoDB doesn't support Join concept so there will be duplicate data in the collections. I want to know the maximum possible size of single collections ?
- Will it have impact on performance in case of updating if document size will be larger ?
- As MongoDB support collections based transactions i.e rollback can be possible in case if transaction is happening on single collection.
  Does it have document/collections based locking mechanism ? can multiple threads update single document at the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is denormalization of your data. If your schema is based upon a distinguished relational structure, you can use references in your documents pointing to related documents in other collections which can then be resolved by your application. The PHP driver for example provides an [API](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodbref.php) for such references, "but they do not load it or automatically follow the link/reference".

MongoDB 3.2 introduces the `$lookup` operator in the aggregation framework to directly reference another collection in the same database.

There is no explicit restriction to the size of a single (non-capped) collection (on 64bit systems); the main restriction is the maximum size of a single document of 16MB with a maximum nesting level of 100. Implicit size restrictions are database size, namespace and index size and maximum number of collections in a database, all depending on the storage engine in use and the underlying OS. See also a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320907/mongodb-billions-of-documents-in-a-collection) on SO.

For collection based transactions, the MongoDB [docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) suggest a Two Phase Commit pattern offering "transaction-like semantics", using a transactions collection and transaction state keys in the updated documents.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question based on my 3 years experience in mongoDB.

1. **Maximum possible size of collection**

   In MongoDB the [maximum possible size](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Database-Size) that you can have on a database is 32TB. If you think your collection is going to exceed that limit then you should consider about [sharding](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/).
2. **Updating document**

   MongoDB performs updates well even if you have millions of documents provided that you have appropriate index set up. One more thing you need to consider about update is that, if your updates are going to change the size of document drastically, then mongoDB needs to move this document to another memory location. This can degrade performance if you do such kind of updates concurrently. But if your application has lot of update operations like this then you need to set appropriate padding factor for your collection. This can be done as described [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/record-padding/). Please note that padding factor is applicable only if you are using MMAPv1 storage engine.
3. **Locking**

   You have to note that mongoDB doesn't support transactions and it provides the ACID property at document level and not at collection level. As per the latest release of MongoDB (v3.0.x), it provides document level locking. There is a full page of items described in MongoDB database that explains about the locking in mongodb. Link [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/). Multiple threads can update the same document only after getting the write lock. Only one thread can hold the write lock at a time. So the update performed by the thread - for which the lock was received at last - will be stored in the collection.

I hope that clears your doubts.

Comment: To expand a bit on concurrent writes: Actually, all write requests are queued by the engine and granted the write lock one after the other until all write operations are either executed or timed out. So in general, there are no real concurrent write operations on the same document – which is exactly the behavior shown by all DBMS acting under lock.

Comment: Well explained Markus